# Reading a file from Rhythmbox plugin

Tags: python, rhythmbox

In my plugin for Rhythmbox I need to read data from xml file. The xml file is the same as the script. I read the file like this :

```
from xml.dom.minidom import parse    
doc = parse('sites.xml')
```

I get an error saying that the file is not found. I figured out that the script look in home folder not in the `/usr/lib/rhythmbox/plugins/myfoder/`. Is it an error of my script or just a limit of Rhythmbox?

Thanks.

Comment: have you tried with os.path.join ?

Comment: add direct address! it gets you error when you tried with something like this? parse("/usr/lib/rhythmbox/plugins/myfoder/sites.xml")?

Comment: It work if I give the complete path. I don't want to do that because the script could be installed else where.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to add direct address.

```
import os
from xml.dom.minidom import parse    
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
xmlfile = os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'sites.xml')
doc = parse(xmlfile)
```